# How can I limit decimal numbers with a variable with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable called "P", and I want to limit the decimal numbers of a float.
The input consists of three lines. The first two lines contain the integer values "a" and "b", respectively. The third line contains the integer p that defines the desired precision. 0<a,b,P≤100 is guaranteed. I want to display the message: "The result of a by b is X.", replacing X with the value of dividing a / b, given to P decimal places.

Ex:

```
input(a) = 10
input(b) = 5
input(p) = 3
expected result: "2.000"
```

Ex:

```
input(a) = 9
input(b) = 3
input(p) = 1
expected result: "3.0"
```

My code: a = 10, b = 5, p = 2

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
P = int(input())
y = round(a / b, P)
print(f'{a} / {b} = {y}.')

output = 10 / 5 = 2.0.
expected output = 10 / 5 = 2.00.
```

Comment: what, exactly is the problem?

Comment: round is not working well, ex: if P is "2", round just return one decimal number.

Comment: What? Please **be specific**. Give an actual example, code we can copy and paste, and provide the output versus the output you were *expecting*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `round()` function does what it's supposed to. The problem is how you want to represent the number. If you *always* want two decimal digits, even if the number has less significant decimal digits (e.g. you want `1.50` printed instead of `1.5`) then you'll have to format the number accordingly when printing:

```
print(f'{a} / {b} = {y:.{P}f}.')
```

Here `.{P}f` is a format specifier for printing a floating point number with exactly `P` decimal digits, no matter how many significant decimal digits it might have. For more info see the doc on [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

In fact, if you only need to print such number, your code could be simplified to avoid using `round()` entirely:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
P = int(input())
print(f'{a} / {b} = {y:.{P}f}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the result display:

```
print(f'O resultado de {a} por {b} é {y:.{P}f}.')
                                       ^^^^^^

10
5
2
O resultado de 10.0 por 5.0 é 2.000.
```